# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 301989896 byte allocation with 16773216 free bytes and 160MB until OOM

Tags: java, android, gson, out-of-memory, sharedpreferences

Hello everyone i have an Array of bitmap images. when i try to save this array in SharedPreferences OutOfMemory:Error

is display. what can i do. i already save my images in different `drawable` like`mdpi,ldpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxhdpi` and also add `android:largeHeap="true"` line in manifest

**got error in this line.**
editor.putString("Array", new Gson().toJson(Combinebitmaps));

**error is this:**

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 301989896 byte
>   allocation with 16773216 free bytes and 160MB until OOM

**my complete code is here.**

```
    ArrayList<Model> Combinebitmaps=new ArrayList<>();
     int arr[]={R.drawable.b1,R.drawable.b2,R.drawable.b3,R.drawable.b4,R.drawable.b5,
R.drawable.b6,R.drawable.b7,R.drawable.b8,R.drawable.b9,R.drawable.b10,
R.drawable.b11,R.drawable.b12,R.drawable.b13,R.drawable.b14,R.drawable.b15,
R.drawable.b16,R.drawable.b17,R.drawable.b18,R.drawable.b19,R.drawable.b20,
R.drawable.b21,R.drawable.b22,R.drawable.b23,R.drawable.b24,R.drawable.b25,
R.drawable.b26};
                for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
              Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), arr[i]);
                    Model model=new Model(bitmap);
                    Combinebitmaps.add(model);
                }
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("ArrayCombine", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor =sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("Array", new Gson().toJson(Combinebitmaps));
                editor.commit();
```

Comment: Don't format question as code.

Comment: lol. so every one need to buy new android when they got this error

Comment: If you wanna to show these images as a list, to the users, and users could choose one of them as wallpaper, why you are showing all pictures in a large size? you can reduce images resolution and show a full-size image if a user wants to saw an image with detail.

Comment: 300MB is quite a lot of memory for an embedded device ...

Comment: It's not clear how and what you wish to do with images but you can assing  index or codename to images and save them to SharedPreferences instead of images. Then, use and if or switch to do whatever you wish with saved indexes as required.

Comment: i don't want  to show these images as a list. i just want to save this Bitmap array in sharedPreferences

Answer (score 1):

Stop trying to save large bitmaps in JSON. Either:

- Leave them as drawable resources, which is what the user wants, or
- Save them as individual bitmap files (PNG, JPEG), which the user will dislike because of the extra I/O time and disk space, but at least it won't be as *much* extra I/O time and as *much* disk space as the approach that you are taking (and failing at)